# Click is being invoked before focusOut event in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, debugging, browser

I have input element which will take input and filter the **contents** and the filter event will be trigger once the user gets focused out from the input element.

When the user having the focus in the input element and he clicks in one of the button, the click event is invoked first and then the focus out event, as it creates conflicts while generating the filtered content.

I tried changing the order of code and other options such as changing the way of invocation of the click event - none of the ways worked out for me

```
 $('body').on('focusout', '.classname', functionname);

 function functionname(e) {
     if (typeof e == 'object') {
     }
 }

 $('body').on('click', '.buttonclass', function (e) {});
```

Could someone help me to build The FocusOut event to trigger first and then the click event.

Comment: Try adding a specific selector instead of "body". Also try debugging your code using console.log  or alert , that which action takes place first and on what action happens what.

Comment: why are you not using that input element?

Comment: RE: comments above: OP is using event delegation, so no doubt the input is being created dynamically.

Comment: Use "onblur" event instead of "onfocusout". onBlur will trigger before the onclick event of the button.

Comment: `onfocusout` and `onblur` should both run before the click event.  I'm not able to reproduce OPs issue using either.  http://jsfiddle.net/u5r8wmgz/

Comment: @VaseemAkram what browser are you using and can your provide reproducible code?  Edit question and add snippet.  Have a read of [mcve]

Comment: I agree with @freedomn-m, the order of events is reversed to the behaviour you're seeing. I would assume that this is possibly caused by the bubbling of the event through the `.classname`/`.butonclass` elements, but without seeing your HTML or a working example of the problem we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the current conditions, you have to - inside the click handler - retrieve the validation result, and based on that result, decide if button submission should or should not occur.

JS Code:

```
$("#input").focusout(function(){    
    var that = this;    
    valid = this.value.length ? true : false;    
    !valid && window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(that).focus();
    }, 0);            
});


$("#button").click(function(e) {    
    if ( !valid ) { return false; }    
    e.preventDefault();    
    alert('execute your filter)');    
 });
```